# Wanderlust: use GPG sign by default

Tags: email, wanderlust

It is possible to manually toggle sign for a message, I wonder how it can be done for any message created?

Answer (score 1):

Just say

```
(setq wl-draft-config-alist
      '((t (mime-edit-pgp-processing . '(sign)))))
```

See Section 7.1.4 of the Wanderlust manual, *Dynamic Modification of Messages*.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create my own function that signs and sends, and use that instead.

(I do not use wanderlust and therefore do not know all of its possibilities).